# phythonを動かせるフレームワークはDjangoでしょうか？

Tags: プログラミング言語

初歩的な質問で恐れいります。
今まで、Laravelを勉強し、開発してきたのですが、phythonは動かせない(動かしずらい）のでしょうか？

サービスにAIの要素を組み込みたいのですが、その場合、フレームワークは、Djangoがよいのでしょうか？

・フレームワークは利用しないPHP
・Laravel
・Django

上記３択になりますが、ご意見お聞かせください。

Comment: 懐かしいですね、[phython: A Python-compatible interpreter implemented in pure PHP](https://bitbucket.org/moriyoshi/phython/src/default/)

Comment: @ななみ さん、Pythonでしょうか、phythonでしょうか？　また、「動かす」としてどのようなことを想定されていらっしゃいますか？　どこが疑問点なのか焦点を絞って頂けると答えやすいです。